# How can I use a variable to get an Input$ in Shiny?

Tags: r, variables, csv, shiny

I am new to R and I am creating a shiny application to read a csv and filter data. I am reading the csv file, then creating dropdowns with a loop using the column names and the unique values:

```
          output$dropdowns <- renderUI({
            if (is.null(x())) {
              return(NULL)
            }
            lapply(1:ncol(x()), function(i) {
              selectInput(names(x()[i]), names(x()[i]), c("ALL", unique(as.character(x()[,i]))))
            })
```

I am now trying to filter the data based on the input from the user. To get the input I am trying to loop through the names (`names(x)[i]`), which is the ID of the selectinput and get the value. But whenever I use `input$names(x)[i]`, I get the following error:

```
            Error: attempt to apply non-function.
```

I have tried to test this using an actual header (e.g. input$testHeader) and this works fine. But when I try to do the same with a variable, e.g.:

```
            a < - "testHeader"
            print(input$a).
```

This returns NULL. I assume it is looking for a selecinput with ID "a" and cannot find it. But I have no idead how else to try?

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: see this [article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) on subsetting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input` is just a [`reactivevalues`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) object so you can use `[[`:

```
print(input[[a]])
```